# ¿Cómo le pido al programa que espere a que el JFrame se cierre para seguir?

Tags: java, java-swing

Pues tengo un programa muy básico por consola y el mismo hecho con swing, también muy básico. He enlazado el segundo en el primero pero no se mantiene abierto, se abre y se cierra

```
while(choice >= 0 && choice <= 3){
        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                saludo.saludo();
                break;

            case 2:
                interaccion.interaccion();
                break;

            case 3:
                NewJFrame nj = new NewJFrame();
                nj.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                nj.setVisible(true);


            case 4:
                System.exit(0);

        }
        System.out.println("Que quieres hacer ahora? \n 1.Ver Saludo \n 2.Calcular Maximo"
                + "\n 3. Salir");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("______________________________________________________"
                + "____________________________________");
    }



    }}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu clase NewJFrame ? Después veo que el `case 4` está de más por que nunca se va a dar ese caso, ya que el `while` lo excluye

Comment: Perdona Juan Rom, no puedo subirte la clase jframe por que la pagina no lo permite, igualmente es basicamente una plantilla, no he escrito el codigo yo mismo si no que he usado la herramienta de netbeans.
Como bien has dicho, el case 4 está mal, muchas gracias. ; )

Answer (score 0):

pensando que la ventana aparecía he buscado una forma de parar el programa y evitar que se cierre, he usado

```
Thread.sleep();
```

y un tiempo suficiente como parametro.